# passing floating point by casting to int and print in ioctl implementation

Tags: c, linux-kernel, ioctl

so I have this code

this is what I am doing in ioctl implementation

```
          if( copy_from_user(&value ,(struct aa*) arg, sizeof(value)) )
          {
                 pr_err("Data Write : Err!\n");
          }
    
         __u64 a=value.a;
    
         __u32 *b=(__u32 *)a;
                    
           
         pr_info("wow Value = [%x]\n", (int)b[0]);
```

but I am passing from userspace float so but my passed values are not correctly printing in printk

this is my program

```
struct aa
{
    uint64_t a;
}; 
#define WR_VALUE _IOW('a','a',struct aa*)
#define RD_VALUE _IOR('a','b',struct aa*)

int main()
{
    struct aa a;
    float *f=(float[]){2,2,3};
    a.a=(uint64_t)f;
    printf("sizeof = %zu\n",sizeof(*f));
    int fd;
    int32_t value, number;

    printf("*********************************\n");
    printf("*******WWW.EmbeTronicX.com*******\n");

    printf("\nOpening Driver\n");
    fd = open("/dev/etx_device", O_RDWR);
    if(fd < 0) {
       printf("Cannot open device file...\n");
       return 0;
    }

    printf("Enter the Value to send\n");
    scanf("%d",&number);
    printf("Writing Value to Driver\n");
    ioctl(fd, WR_VALUE, (struct aa *) &a); 

    printf("Reading Value from Driver\n");
    ioctl(fd, RD_VALUE, (struct aa*) &a);
    printf("Value is %d\n", value);

    printf("Closing Driver\n");
    close(fd);
}
```

full code

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kdev_t.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include<linux/slab.h>                 //kmalloc()
#include<linux/uaccess.h>              //copy_to/from_user()
#include <linux/ioctl.h>
#include <asm/fpu/api.h>
struct aa
{
    __u64 a;
};
 
#define WR_VALUE _IOW('a','a',struct aa *)
#define RD_VALUE _IOR('a','b',struct aa *)
 
struct aa value;
 
dev_t dev = 0;
static struct class *dev_class;
static struct cdev etx_cdev;

/*
** Function Prototypes
*/
static int      __init etx_driver_init(void);
static void     __exit etx_driver_exit(void);
static int      etx_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file);
static int      etx_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *file);
static ssize_t  etx_read(struct file *filp, char __user *buf, size_t len,loff_t * off);
static ssize_t  etx_write(struct file *filp, const char *buf, size_t len, loff_t * off);
static long     etx_ioctl(struct file *file, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg);

/*
** File operation sturcture
*/
static struct file_operations fops =
{
        .owner          = THIS_MODULE,
        
        .open           = etx_open,
        .unlocked_ioctl = etx_ioctl,
        .release        = etx_release,
};

/*
** This function will be called when we open the Device file
*/
static int etx_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
       
        return 0;
}

/*
** This function will be called when we close the Device file
*/
static int etx_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
       
        return 0;
}



static long etx_ioctl(struct file *file, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
{
         switch(cmd) {
                case WR_VALUE:
                        if( copy_from_user(&value ,(struct aa*) arg, sizeof(value)) )
                        {
                                pr_err("Data Write : Err!\n");
                        }
        
               __u64 a=value.a;
        
               __u32 *b=(__u32 *)a;
                        
               
                        pr_info("wow Value = [%x]\n", (int)b[0]);
        kernel_fpu_end();
                        break;
                case RD_VALUE:
                        if( copy_to_user((struct aa*) arg, &value, sizeof(value)) )
                        {
                                pr_err("Data Read : Err!\n");
                        }
                        break;
                default:
                        pr_info("Default\n");
                        break;
        }
        return 0;
}
 
/*
** Module Init function
*/
static int __init etx_driver_init(void)
{
        /*Allocating Major number*/
        if((alloc_chrdev_region(&dev, 0, 1, "etx_Dev")) <0){
                pr_err("Cannot allocate major number\n");
                return -1;
        }
        pr_info("Major = %d Minor = %d \n",MAJOR(dev), MINOR(dev));
 
        /*Creating cdev structure*/
        cdev_init(&etx_cdev,&fops);
 
        /*Adding character device to the system*/
        if((cdev_add(&etx_cdev,dev,1)) < 0){
            pr_err("Cannot add the device to the system\n");
            goto r_class;
        }
 
        /*Creating struct class*/
        if((dev_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE,"etx_class")) == NULL){
            pr_err("Cannot create the struct class\n");
            goto r_class;
        }
 
        /*Creating device*/
        if((device_create(dev_class,NULL,dev,NULL,"etx_device")) == NULL){
            pr_err("Cannot create the Device 1\n");
            goto r_device;
        }
        pr_info("Device Driver Insert...Done!!!\n");
        return 0;
 
r_device:
        class_destroy(dev_class);
r_class:
        unregister_chrdev_region(dev,1);
        return -1;
}

/*
** Module exit function
*/
static void __exit etx_driver_exit(void)
{
        device_destroy(dev_class,dev);
        class_destroy(dev_class);
        cdev_del(&etx_cdev);
        unregister_chrdev_region(dev, 1);
        pr_info("Device Driver Remove...Done!!!\n");
}
 
module_init(etx_driver_init);
module_exit(etx_driver_exit);
 
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("EmbeTronicX <embetronicx@gmail.com>");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Simple Linux device driver (IOCTL)");
MODULE_VERSION("1.5");
```

what am I doing wrong in kernel ioctl because I casted float to `uint_64` like `a.a=(uint64_t)f;` and passed `struct a` to kernel now I want to read `float *f` elements passed from userspace through ioctl in ioctl implementation

Comment: For one thing, you're not passing the value you read from the user.  You're asking the user to enter a number, and you're reading it with `scanf("%d",&number)`, but then you're not doing anything with `number`.  Similarly, when your second `ioctl` call returns something, you're not printing it, but rather, you're printing the uninitialized value of the unrelated variable `value`.

Comment: You're also doing something very strange with your `struct aa`.  Although its member `a` is a `uint64_t`, you're using it as a pointer.  You're passing a pointer to three floats.  In your driver, you're trying to print the first one as an `int`.  This *might* work (and if it does, you'll see an integer representation of the *bit pattern* of the float, not the value of the float), but to get it to work I suspect you'll need another `copy_from_user` call for the data pointed to by `b`.

Comment: What I mean by "an integer representation of the bit pattern of the float" is that, for that first value 2.0 in your array `f`, I would expect it to print as `40000000`, *not* `00000002`.  In IEEE-754 single-precision floating point, the bit pattern for the value 2.0 is `0x40000000`.

Comment: `float *f = ..;  a.a=(uint64_t)f;`  you are passing _an address_ to an array of floats, not a float. `,struct aa*)` also you are passing _only_ the _address_ to `aa`, not `struct aa`.

Comment: @KamilCuk yes but what I need to do to print f values without using float again